# How to find the list of all builtin functions of Julia

Tags: julia, built-in

How to get the list of all built-in functions of Julia Programming Language?

Once the Julia command line is started, what functions can I use and how to get the list of builtins?

I mean without importing any modules from the standard library (e.g. `using LinearAlgebra`).

For Python it is documented here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

Is there a similar documentation for Julia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to get it programmatically, first you need the list of loaded modules:

```
julia> modules= [mod for mod in getfield.(Ref(Main),names(Main)) 
                 if typeof(mod)==Module && mod != Main]
3-element Vector{Module}:
 Base
 Core
 InteractiveUtils
```

Now you having the list of modules you can do:

```
julia> vcat(( filter!(f -> typeof(f) <: Function, 
              getfield.(Ref(m), names(m)))  for m in modules)...)
835-element Vector{Any}:
 ! (generic function with 4 methods)
 != (generic function with 4 methods)
 !== (generic function with 1 method)
 rem (generic function with 142 methods)
 & (generic function with 17 methods)
 adjoint (generic function with 48 methods)
 * (generic function with 310 methods)
 + (generic function with 207 methods)
 - (generic function with 211 methods)
 / (generic function with 137 methods)
 // (generic function with 8 methods)
 (::Colon) (generic function with 16 methods)
 < (generic function with 74 methods)
 ⋮
 clipboard (generic function with 3 methods)
 code_llvm (generic function with 8 methods)
 code_native (generic function with 5 methods)
 code_warntype (generic function with 4 methods)
 edit (generic function with 9 methods)
 less (generic function with 5 methods)
 methodswith (generic function with 4 methods)
 peakflops (generic function with 2 methods)
 subtypes (generic function with 2 methods)
 supertypes (generic function with 1 method)
 varinfo (generic function with 4 methods)
 versioninfo (generic function with 2 methods)
```

Answer (score 4):

The ["Base"](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Standard-Modules) section of the Julia documentation says:

> `Core` is the module that contains all identifiers considered "built in" to the language, i.e. part of the core language and not libraries. Every module implicitly specifies `using Core`, since you can't do anything without those definitions.

and

> `Base`
> The base library of Julia. Base is a module that contains basic functionality (the contents of base/). All modules implicitly contain `using Base`, since this is needed in the vast majority of cases.

It seems that the contents of `Core` and `Base` which are always available are listed in the ["All Objects"](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#All-Objects) section, but I did not find an overview comparable to that in the Python documentation.

If you start an interactive Julia session and type <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> at the `julia>` prompt, it prints a list of names that are available for autocompletion.

Comment: Can I get list of the bultins of Core from the command line by executing some command?

Comment: Last few operators are not visible in my Windows 10 command line. pi in included and visible.

Comment: Type `Core.<tab><tab>` in the REPL.