# How to get help contents of a function as a string iteratively in Julia

Tags: julia, docstring

If I type `?cos` in Julia command line the following help contents will turn up.

> help?> cos search: cos cosh cosd cosc cospi acos acosh acosd sincos
> sincosd sincospi const close isconst copysign MathConstants
>
> cos(x)
>
> Compute cosine of x, where x is in radians.
>
> See also [cosd], [cospi], [sincos], [cis].
>
> ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
>
> cos(A::AbstractMatrix)
>
> Compute the matrix cosine of a square matrix A.
>
> If A is symmetric or Hermitian, its eigendecomposition (eigen) is
> used to compute the cosine. Otherwise, the cosine   is determined by
> calling exp.
>
> Examples   ≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡
>
> julia> cos(fill(1.0, (2,2)))   2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
> 0.291927  -0.708073    -0.708073   0.291927

I get this help content string in a variable using `@doc` function : a = `@doc cos`.

I have asked a question here to get all builtin functions in Julia: [How to find the list of all builtin functions of Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75649652/how-to-find-the-list-of-all-builtin-functions-of-julia)

I am trying to write the help contents of all the modules to a file here:

```
function test()
modules= [mod for mod in getfield.(Ref(Main),names(Main)) if typeof(mod)==Module && mod != Main]
fns = vcat(( filter!(f -> typeof(f) <: Function, getfield.(Ref(m), names(m)))  for m in modules)...)

f = open("G:/avc/Programs/Julia/BuiltinFns.md","w")

for fn in fns
    a = string(fn)
    b = @doc a
    write(f,a*"\n"*(string(b))*"\n\n")
end

close(f)

end

test()
```

which is giving an error :

```
ERROR: LoadError: cannot document the following expression:

write(f, a * "\n" * string(b) * "\n\n")

Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String, ::String)
   @ Base .\error.jl:42
 [2] test()
   @ Main G:\avc\Programs\Julia\GetAllFunctionDocs.jl:11
 [3] top-level scope
   @ G:\avc\Programs\Julia\GetAllFunctionDocs.jl:19
 [4] include(fname::String)
   @ Base.MainInclude .\client.jl:451
 [5] top-level scope
   @ REPL[59]:1
in expression starting at G:\avc\Programs\Julia\GetAllFunctionDocs.jl:19
```

How to get the help string of `fn` in `b`: `b = @doc a`

I want to get help contents written to a file and go through for learning purposes when there is no access to julia.

Answer (score 2):

When you assign:

```
b = @doc cos;
```

Than the object `b` is of a type `Markdown.MD`

```
julia> typeof(b)
Markdown.MD
```

If you want to output that to file you need to convert it to `String`. Try:

```
julia> using Markdown

julia> println(Markdown.plain(b))
```